# How to combine multiple dropdowns and input fields to single tag field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I enter multiple tags in a field?

So below is my code so far. I have five fields. The first two are separate, the next two are related, and the last one is where all the tags should go.

I want want the first two drop downs (color and shapes) to only contribute one tag each to the full tag field.

I want the input field and the last drop down to be combined and be able to enter multiple tags. How can I do that?

So as an example the full tag field could be populated with the following:

color: red, shape: circle, food: burgers, food: french fries, drink: coke, drink: pepsi, drink: orange juice, clothes: nike, clothes: adidas, container: pyrex

```js
function myFunction() {
  var taginput = $('#taginput').val();
  var tagdropdown = $('#tagdropdown').val();
  $('#fulltag').val(tagdropdown + ": " + taginput);
}

function myFunction2() {
  var tagcolordropdown = $('#tagcolordropdown').val();
  var tagdropdown = $('#tagdropdown').val();
  $('#fulltag').val("color: " + tagcolordropdown);
}

function myFunction3() {
  var tagshapedropdown = $('#tagshapedropdown').val();
  $('#fulltag').val("color: " + tagshapedropdown);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <label for="tagcolordropdown">What colors are in the picture?:</label>
  <select id="tagcolordropdown">
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Green ">Green</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Add Color As Tag" onclick="myFunction2()"><br><br>

  <label for="tagshapedropdown">What shapes are in the pictures:</label>
  <select id="tagshapedropdown">
    <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
    <option value="Square">Square</option>
    <option value="Rectangle">Rectangle</option>
    <option value="Pentagon ">Pentagon</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Add Shape As Tag" onclick="myFunction3()"><br><br>

  <label for="taginput">Enter a Tag:</label> Type the name of a food, drink, clothing that relates to your image.
  <input type="text" id="taginput" name="taginput"><br><br>

  <label for="tagdropdown">Select a Description to Match the Tag:</label> From the drop down, please select the term which best describes your tag.
  <select id="tagdropdown">
    <option value="Food">Food</option>
    <option value="Drink">Drink</option>
    <option value="Clothes">Clothes</option>
    <option value="Containers ">Containers</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <input type="button" value="Combine" onclick="myFunction()">
  <br><br>
  <label for="fulltag">Full tag:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fulltag" name="fulltag" disabled><br><br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the values in array and join them once the action has been done. See example below.

Your code, however, need some changes. You are using jQuery but assigning events through onclick attribute instead of jQuery way which is using selectors.

```js
let fullArray = [];

function myFunction() {
  var taginput = $('#taginput').val();
  var tagdropdown = $('#tagdropdown').val();
  fullArray.push(tagdropdown + ": " + taginput);
  combineValues();
}

function myFunction2() {
  var tagcolordropdown = $('#tagcolordropdown').val();
  var tagdropdown = $('#tagdropdown').val();
  fullArray.unshift("color: " + tagcolordropdown);
  combineValues();
}

function myFunction3() {
  var tagshapedropdown = $('#tagshapedropdown').val();
  fullArray.unshift("shape: " + tagshapedropdown);
  combineValues();
}

function combineValues() {
  $('#fulltag').val(fullArray.join(","));
}
```

```css
#fulltag {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <label for="tagcolordropdown">What colors are in the picture?:</label>
  <select id="tagcolordropdown">
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="Green ">Green</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Add Color As Tag" onclick="myFunction2()"><br><br>

  <label for="tagshapedropdown">What shapes are in the pictures:</label>
  <select id="tagshapedropdown">
    <option value="Circle">Circle</option>
    <option value="Square">Square</option>
    <option value="Rectangle">Rectangle</option>
    <option value="Pentagon ">Pentagon</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Add Shape As Tag" onclick="myFunction3()"><br><br>

  <label for="taginput">Enter a Tag:</label> Type the name of a food, drink, clothing that relates to your image.
  <input type="text" id="taginput" name="taginput"><br><br>

  <label for="tagdropdown">Select a Description to Match the Tag:</label> From the drop down, please select the term which best describes your tag.
  <select id="tagdropdown">
    <option value="Food">Food</option>
    <option value="Drink">Drink</option>
    <option value="Clothes">Clothes</option>
    <option value="Containers ">Containers</option>
  </select><br><br>

  <input type="button" value="Combine" onclick="myFunction()">
  <br><br>
  <label for="fulltag">Full tag:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fulltag" name="fulltag" disabled><br><br>

</form>
```